# Mod_Rewrite .Htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a problem which I could not find during my online search.

I have successfully made a wildcard sub-domain and any sub domain to the main domain points to the folder.

I am looking to create link URI to Parameters like

1- .domain.com/location/locationname
to
2- .domain.com//location.php? locname=

and then

1- .domain.com/location/locationname/category/categoryname/item/itemname
to
2- .domain.com//orderitem.php?locname=locationname&ordercategory=categoryname&orderitem=itemname

(2) is happening in the backend and user still sees (1)

How will it work? Do I have to make table in MySQL, which I am not sure how it will go around.
Second is to explode the URL and link to specific URL like orderloc or ordermenu or orderitem etc.

Any help will be a step closer.

Thanks

Comment: So what is your initial url and do you want your final url to be?

Comment: (2) shows the backend or how my original urls looks like. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^location/(.*)/category/(.*)/item/(.*) //orderitem.php?locname=$1&ordercategory=$2&orderitem=$3\? [L]
RewriteRule ^location/(.*) //location.php?locname=\? [L]
```

It will show `domain.com/location/locationname` to the user, but the backend will see `domain.com//location.php?locname=

and `domain.com/location/locationname/category/categoryname/item/itemname` to the user, but the backend will see `domain.com//orderitem.php?locname=locationname&ordercategory=categoryname&orderitem=itemname`

Comment: Thanks Howlin. What about the sub domain part? I think it has cut off because of my in vain effort to make it clearer :) . subdomain refers to user name. How will it work if it is to become part as parameter

Comment: Can you give an example of one?

Comment: {subdomain}.domain.com/location/{locationname}/category/{categoryname}/item/{itemname} to domain.com/orderitem.php?location={locationname}&category={categoryname}&item={itemname}&username={subdomain}